# Best indian payment gateway which has recurring payment option

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, paypal, payment-gateway, recurring-billing

I am developing an **Ruby on Rails** web application which include monthly subscription in India. So if you suggest me some India payment gateway which has recurring billing option then it would be very helpful. I know **paypal and recurly** payment gateways are has this option but my problem is they are not accepting money in Indian currency. So now payPal updating their API which is currently accepting only US business. So please suggest me some of the payment gateway in India or any other gateways.

2. Suppose if I use paypal will it debit the amount in Indian Rupee or what is there payment process flow?
3. I am doing lot of R&D in this but please help because i'm new to payment process.

Thanks for all of your reply.
 **Is that possible to make recurring payment using Indian payment gateways?**

Answer (score 1):

Check this payment gateway

[Payza](http://www.payza.com/)

[TimesofMoney](http://www.timesofmoney.com)

Answer (score 1):

Paypal offers the option to choose your currency.
If you choose INR (Rupees) as your currency then no matter in which currency you receive the payment, it will automatically be converted to INR and then transferred to your bank account because due to RBI regulation, Indian are not allowed to have any kind of money balance online. The conversion rates offered by Paypal are just a little lower than the market rates.

I still recommend you to go with Paypal as it is preferred by most of the people.

If you don't want to go with paypal then you can look at Payza, Skrill/money bookers, payoneer etc

Comment: Thanks for your response. check this https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/sell/mc/mc_intro-outside. i think paypal won't accept indian currency. we should make transaction only in US currency? is that true. if yes then how will they make money conversion. please help me..

Comment: They will accept payment in USD and then convert it to INR according to market rate (currently 1 usd is worth about 53 INR) and pay you in INR (Rupees).

Answer (score 1):

1. CCAvenue.com: Probably the biggest 3rd party player providing the best of services. Also the most expensive.

   Users: Flipkart
2. EBS.in: Second best player. Prices can be negotiated. Preferred choice of most startups these days due to the prices and good quality.

   Users: Sanjay Goel
3. Direcpay
4. ICICI Payseal
5. HDFC
6. Payu.in
7. Zaakpay.com

Comment: [see this too](http://www.onside.in/top-10-trusted-online-payment-gateways-for-ecommerce-websites-in-india/)

Comment: None of these support Recurring options within India